# Elevator problem

Tags: algorithms

I came across on interesting puzzle. 
Suppose there is elevator, located at some floor (let it is "source" floor). There is also another "target" floor. Can elevator reach "target" floor? besides, elevator has some restrictions. It can move up with $a>0$ and down with $b>0$ floors.

How to solve this problem analytically?
Maybe there is formalized math problem with well explored solutions?

Edit: count of floors is limited. More over, solution can be absent.

Comment: Well, if $\gcd (a,b)\neq 1$ there can be an obstruction.  If the elevator is, say, on floor $0$ and wants to get to floor $1$ but $a,b$ are both even then it is impossible.  Also there can be an obstruction if the number of floors is limited.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. Problem implies that floors are limited and solution can be absent.

Comment: @lulu, that's an answer.

Comment: Hint: Bezout's Identity

Comment: Euclid's algorith says we can get $ka - jb = \pm\gcd(a,b)$ where k and j are non-neg.  So we can either go up or down any multiple of $\gcd(a,b)$ floors.  The question is can we find positive values of $ka - jb = \gcd(a,b)$ and $k'a - j'b = -\gcd(a,b)$.  If so we can go to all multiple of such floors.  *If* this is an infinite number of floors.